# Why fields are not initialized correctly when I invoke a base class method (this method initialize the fields) in a subclass?

Tags: java

I have a class called SimplePolygon which has a field as array called vertices. And there is a factory method called getNewPoly that invokes SimplePolygon constructor and returns a polygon. Inside getNewPoly(), 'vertices' is initialized as a result of invoking SimplePolygon constructor.
What I did is I invoked getNewPoly in a constructor of a subclass called ConvexPolygon then I created a convexPolygon object then I called the length of vertices field for convexPolygon and It gave me 0. So what's wrong ?

```
protected int n; // number of vertices of the polygon
protected Point2D.Double[] vertices; // vertices[0..n-1] around the polygon
protected static Line2D.Double[] edges;

 protected SimplePolygon(int size) {
    n = size;
    vertices = new Point2D.Double[n]; // creates array with n size. Elements
                                        // are doubles.

}

/** default no-parameter constructor */
protected SimplePolygon() {
    vertices = new Point2D.Double[0];
}

/********* public getters & toString ***************/

/**
 * static factory method constructs and returns an unverified
 * simple-polygon, initialised according to user provided input data. Runs
 * in O(n) time.
 * 
 * @return an unverified simple-polygon instance
 */
public static SimplePolygon getNewPoly() {
    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("vertices"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int size = 0; // Number of edges of the polygon.

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding every line from the file in an array list.
    while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(fileIn.nextLine());
        size++;
    }
    int noOfCoordinates = size * 2;
    Point2D.Double[] vertices = new Point2D.Double[size];
    ArrayList<java.lang.Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<java.lang.Double>();
    ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

    // Make every line a string tokenizer then split the string tokenizer
    // into two tokens then converting these tokens into double. Finally
    // adding these double values to 'coordinates' array list.
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(lines.get(i));
        while (line.hasMoreTokens()) {
            double coordinate = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(line
                    .nextToken());
            coordinates.add(coordinate);
        }
    }

    // Taking the double values in 'coordinates' array list and create by
    // them
    // Point2D.Double then adding these Point2D into an array list.
    for (int z = 0; z < coordinates.size(); z += 2) {
        Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(coordinates.get(z),
                coordinates.get(z + 1));
        points.add(point); // add the Point2D.Double points to 'points'
                            // array list.
    }

    SimplePolygon polygon = new SimplePolygon(size);

    // Finally adding Point2D to 'vertices' array.
    for (int x = 0; x < points.size(); x++) {
        vertices[x] = points.get(x);
    }

    for (int e = 0; e < polygon.vertices.length; e++) {
        polygon.vertices[e] = points.get(e);
    }

    edges = new Line2D.Double[size];

    for (int n = 0; n < vertices.length; n++) {
        if (n == vertices.length - 1)
            edges[n] = new Line2D.Double(vertices[n], vertices[0]);
        else
            edges[n] = new Line2D.Double(vertices[n], vertices[n + 1]);
    }

    return polygon;
}
```

Code for the subclass:

```
public class ConvexPolygon extends SimplePolygon {

        protected ConvexPolygon()
        {
            super.getNewPoly();

        }
    }
```

Test code:

```
        ConvexPolygon poly = new ConvexPolygon();
        System.out.println(poly.vertices.length);
```

Comment: Create a *minimal* test-case, with relevant class definitions and none of the irrelevant polygon generation code. Superclass constructors are guaranteed to run before the subclass constructor executes; the problem with "constructors" only exists in the *other* direction than described - mainly, when a superclass constructor attempts to access a member variable assigned in a subclass constructor. (Anyway, I suspect the issue is that the default-constructor was called, which creates an array-of-length-0.. but I'm not shifting through that.)

Comment: Don't describe code, share [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) It doesn't look like you need to call "super.getNewPoly()", `getNewPoly()` should suffice.  2) It looks like you're successfully invoking constructor `SimplePolygon()` ... which creates a zero-element array.  3) If in doubt ... *THEN USE THE DEBUGGER*.  Set a breakpoint in `getNewPoly()` and step through the code!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a false assumption on what your code does. Look at your constructor:

```
 protected ConvexPolygon()
 {
        super.getNewPoly();
 }
```

This will first invoke the default constructor of the superclass (since you are not calling another constructor implicitly), initializing `this.vertices` as an empty array. After that, you are calling the *static* method  `getNewPoly()` from the superclass, creating a new instance of `SimplePolygon` unrelated to `this`. Since you are not even keeping a reference to the result, this line has no effect.

Applying a factory pattern in this way won't work, but you could make `getNewPoly` an instance method, possibly name it `load` (careful with shadowing variable names though!), and call that from the subclass constructor.